# Achemso superscript for numbered bib

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, achemso

I am not all that experienced in using the achemso style package. I am trying to prepare an article for Environmental science & research. They want the references as super-scripted numbers in the end of the sentences after the punctuation.

To my understanding this should be the default when using:

```
\documentclass[journal=esthag,manuscript=article]{achemso}
```

using in the text `\cite{nameofarticle_xxxx}` and implementing the bibliography file as: `\bibliography{nameofbibfile}`.

However my references show up as numbers in normal text and before the punctuation mark. How do I get them super scripted and behind the punctuation mark? Is there a setting I am missing?

The following MWE shows the issue:

```
\documentclass[journal=esthag,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{super=true}
\begin{filecontents}{acsdemo.bib}
@ARTICLE{Abernethy2003,
  author = {Colin D. Abernethy and Gareth M. Codd and Mark D. Spicer
    and Michelle K. Taylor},
  title = {{A} highly stable {N}-heterocyclic carbene complex of
    trichloro-oxo-vanadium(\textsc{v}) displaying novel
    {C}l---{C}(carbene) bonding interactions},
  journal = {{J}. {A}m. {C}hem. {S}oc.},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {125},
  pages = {1128--1129},
  number = {5},
  doi = {10.1021/ja0276321},
}
\end{filecontents}
\title{Demo title}
\begin{document}
This is a citation\cite{Abernethy2003}.
\bibliography{acsdemo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help is most appreciated

Comment: Look at the package documentation: sse the `super` package option. Placing the super-scripted number before the punctuation should be the default, see Sec. 7 'The natmove package' in the docs.

Comment: I have tried adding the following line, but it does not seem to make any difference: \setkeys{acs}{super=true}. And I have read the info on the natmove package and agree it should be the default, however my output does not show up the intended way. Also I use miktex in combination with texmaker, could this cause it not to behave?

Comment: You are right, setting the `super` option seems not to work. With `journal=esthag` I could not switch on the superscripts, and with `journal=jacsat`, which is what `achemso-demo.tex` uses, I couldn't switch it off. I'll post an answer as addition to your question.

Answer (score 9):

This is an error in `achemso` which will be fixed in the next release. For the moment, doing

```
\documentclass[journal=esthag,manuscript=article]{achemso}
\setkeys{acs}{super = true}
\setcitestyle{super,open={},close={}}
\def\citenumfont{}
```

should correct the issues: this resets the flag for `achemso` and alters the appropriate `natbib` settings.